# Android ListFragment onclick issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I am trying to create a ListFragment using BaseAdapter. But my onItemClick event is not working when i use custom Adapter. i do get my desired view but my on Item click is not firing with CustomAdapter.

I am using following code

```
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //following code do not fire on click event
        setListAdapter(new TestListAdapter(getActivity(), test)); //test is a Arraylist

//following code perfectly fine
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three"}));

}
```

and this is my TestListAdapter

```
class TestListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    private ArrayList<Xyz> tests;
    private Context mContext;
    TestListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Xyz> tests){
        //super(context, tests);
         mContext=context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.tests=tests;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return tests.size();

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return tests.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_row, null);
        TextView tvName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.testName); // title

        return view;
    }


}
```

i have overridden following function and that is how i know it working with ArrayAdapter.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Log.d("XYZ","click.......");

}
```

Comment: What views do you have in the `R.layout.my_list_row`?

Comment: Its a custom layout contain multiple views TextView, ImageView, CheckBox

Comment: The `CheckBox` or other widgets like `ImageButtons`, `Buttons` should be made non focusable.

Answer (score 1):

Your list view has a TextView. So onListItemClick() does not fire.

Set focusable, clickable property of TextView (or other listview children) false.